# writing generic function in java

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a function which would return me a Vector of the specified type which I pass to it. For example:

```
// Here getNewVector(<ClassType>) should return me an integer Vector.
Vector<Integer> myIntVector = getNewVector(Integer.class);
//should get a String vector in this case and so on.
Vector<String> myStringVector = getNewVector(String.class) ;
```

I want to implement `getVector(Class classType)` in such a way so as to return a new vector of that particular class type. How can we achieve it without using reflections and by not passing the class name as a String(I would like to pass the class type only as I had mentioned in the example above.)

Actually, I want a function getVector() somewhat like this..

```
Vector<T> getVector(T t) {
    return new Vector<t>();
}
```

Comment: I'd think twice about using a Vector. Have you considered using a List instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [Java Tutorial for Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).  Here's one way to do what you want:

```
public static <T> Vector<T> getVector(Class<T> clazz) {
  return new Vector<T>()
}

public static <T> Vector<T> getVector(T t) {
  Vector<T> vector = new Vector<T>();
  vector.add(t);
  return vector;
}
```

I'm assuming that you're not going to just want to throw away the `t` you pass into `getVector(T t)`, so I stuck it in the `Vector`.

Theoretically, you don't need to pass anything into the method if all you want is the typing mechanism:

```
public static <T> Vector<T> getVector() {
  return new Vector<T>();
}

//Usage
Vector<Integer> vector = getVector();
```

Java can figure out that you want it typed as a `Vector<Integer>` from the generic typing on the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

```
public <T> Vector<T> getNewVector(Class<T> type) {
    return new Vector<T>();
}
```

Comment: Seems like that should be a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Why even bother writing a function here?

```
Vector<Integer> myIntVector = new Vector<Integer>();
```

or, even better, if you're on Java 7,

```
Vector<Integer> myIntVector = new Vector<>();
```

(There's no actual difference at runtime, of course, between vector types with different element types.)